# List<Object> conversion from netcore server api in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a list of objects(`List<Object>` in Flutter) to a defined type(class) in a flutter project. I have tried examples on converting the list as shown in [Serializing Your Object in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47) . Every time I get `Map<String, dynamic>` is not a subtype of `List<dynamic>`. But tried something different, same error. Posted is the sample code for the latter not from [Serializing Your Object in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47). Is there an alternative to achieving this? Really appreciate your responses. **[Updated]**

Custom Object

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Activity{
  String id;
  String name;
  double amount;

  Activity({ this.amount, this.name , this.id});  

  Activity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){ 
      id = json["id"];
      name = json["name"];
      amount = json["amount"];
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {      
      'id' : id,
      'name' : name,
      'amount' : amount,
  };
}
```

Sample Flutter Screen

```
initiateConnection(){
    var builder = HubConnectionBuilder();
    this._hubConnection = builder.withUrl("##########################").build();

    _hubConnection.onclose( (error) => print("Connection Closed"));

    this._hubConnection.on("Activities", formActivityDashboard );

    this._hubConnection.start().then((data) => print("Connected"));
  }

  formActivityDashboard(List<Object> data){
    final items = (data).map((i) => new Activity.fromJson(i));
    for (final item in items) {
      print(item.id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @JulienLachal . Okay one minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<dynamic>ActivityList=json.decode(response.body);
List<Activity> myActivityList = new List();

      for(int i=0;i<ActivityList.length;i++)
      {
        Map<String, dynamic>ActivityData = ActivityList.elementAt(i);
        Activity act=new Activity();
        act.id=ActivityData['id']
        act.name=ActivityData['name']
        act.amount=ActivityData['amount']

        myActivityList.add(act);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks will try that Mahmoud

Comment: Same result @Mahmoud

Comment: @D_Edet the error is clear response data is List<dynamic> and you try to get it into Map<String, dynamic> i think your response is list of list not list of object this is why you get this error

Comment: I am sure the server returns a list of objects. An angular client app works well with the List, which is converted to a list type defined in the angular app. List conversion is the challenge in flutter. The server actually sends a list of objects, not a string.

Comment: My sincere apologies for replying now. Yes I am supposed to show you my response body. Just noticed, I was wrong. The server is returning a list of list not list of objects. I don't know why. I will go ahead and iterate through the same, making use of the first list. Thanks alot.